# Java 2D List won't print after the 6th entity

Tags: java

I am working on a memory game.

For some reason I get this error message when printing the number pairs to the console. It is a 5x5 grid of number pairs.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Views.ConsoleView.<init>(ConsoleView.java:20)
at Controllers.MemoryApplication.<init>(MemoryApplication.java:19)
at main.main(main.java:9)
```

---

Code to fill the list, the printline at the arrow gives me the following output:

6 9 7 4 7 12 5 3 10 5 1 1 4 11 8 10 2 6 8 9 3 2 11 12 7 9 10 4 4 6 12 7 5 6 8 8 2 10 3 1 11 3 12 9 2 1 11 5

```
public MemoryModel()
{
    numberOfRows = 5;
    numberOfColumns = 5;
    tiles = new Tile[numberOfRows][numberOfColumns];

    fillTileList();
}

//Fill list of tiles
public void fillTileList()
{
    //Fill a lis with the to be distributed number pairs & shuffle
    ArrayList<Integer> numbersToDistribute = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ((numberOfColumns*numberOfRows)/2); i++) {
        numbersToDistribute.add(i+1);
        numbersToDistribute.add(i+1);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(numbersToDistribute);

    //Fill ths list of tiles & assign number pairs
    for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++)
        {
            //Check if the middle tile is being processed
            //Check if the total amount of tiles is odd
            if(row == gridMiddle && column == gridMiddle && (row*column)%2 != 0)
            {
                tiles[gridMiddle][gridMiddle] = null;
            }
            else
            {
                //Add tile to the list & assign number to the tile
                tiles[row][column] = new Tile(numbersToDistribute.get(0));
      ========> System.out.print(tiles[row][column].getNumber() + " ");
                //Remove number
                numbersToDistribute.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}


//Properties
public int getNumberOfRows() {
    return numberOfRows;
}

public int getNumberOfColumns() {
    return numberOfColumns;
}

public Tile[][] getTiles() {
    return tiles;
}

public List<Tile> getGuesses() {
    return guesses;
}

public Timer getTimer() {
    return timer;
}
```

The view that has to print to the console, gives me the following output:

As you can see the first 6 numbers are printed correctly and are the same as the first 6 numbers above, but for some reason it crashes at the 7th number.

6 9 7 4 7

12

```
public ConsoleView(MemoryModel model)
{
    Tile[][] tiles = model.getTiles();

    System.out.println("--- Console View Memory ---");
    for (int row = 0; row < model.getNumberOfRows(); row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < model.getNumberOfColumns(); column++)
        {
            System.out.print(tiles[row][column].getNumber()+ " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print("----------------------------");

}
```

---

EDIT 1: Added Tile Class

```
package Models;

public class Tile
{
    //Fields
    private int number;
    private boolean selected;
    private boolean guessed;

    public Tile(int number)
    {
       this.number = number;
    }

    //Properties
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public boolean isGuessed() {
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error might be originating from the method getNumber() of the Tile class. Please post the code for the same.

Comment: Added the Tile class, which contains the getNumber method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(row == gridMiddle && column == gridMiddle && (row*column)%2 != 0)
{
    tiles[gridMiddle][gridMiddle] = null;
}
```

In this section, you're setting one of the entries in the Tiles array to `null`.

```
System.out.print(tiles[row][column].getNumber()+ " ");
```

In this section, you're calling the `getNumber()` function on each object in that array. That includes the `null` value.

Also, it seems your gridMiddle is set to 1, I'm guessing it should be 2 here (for a 5x5 grid)

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks!